# would not assign infomation on the database

Tags: php, database

I really have a problem and it is such that it would not just infomation up the database.

```
<?php
    include("include/database/database.php");

    //Infomation
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
    $gentag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["gentag"]);
    $facebook = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["facebook"]);
    $land = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["land"]);
    $profiltekst = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["profiltekst"]);
    $djnavn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["djnavn"]);
    $site = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["site"]);
    $fk_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["kategori"]);
    $errorCount = 0;

    $billedefilnavn = null;

    include("include/class.upload.php");

    $handle = new Upload($_FILES['file']);

    if($handle->uploaded){

            //lidt mere store billeder
            $handle->image_resize = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
            $handle->image_x = 220;
            $handle->Process("picthumb/storeimg");

            //til profil billede lign..
                $handle->image_resize = true;
                $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                $handle->image_y = 75;
                $handle->image_x = 75;
                $handle->Process("picthumb");

    $billedefilnavn = $handle->file_dst_name;

        echo "Dit billede blev upload<br>";

    }else {
        echo "Fejl; Du skal uploade en fil<br>";
    }

     if($email == "")
     {
        echo "Du skal indtaste et Email som brugernavn.<br>";
        $errorCount++;
     }
     if($password == "")
     {
        echo "Du skal indtaste et password.<br>";
        $errorCount++;
     }
     if($gentag == "" || $gentag != $password)
     {
        echo "De to passwordfelter skal have ens indhold.<br>";
        $errorCount++;
     }


    $password = sha1($password);
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO brugere (email,password,facebook,land,profiltekst,email,site,fk_musik_info,profilbillede) VALUES ('$email','$password','$facebook','$land','$profiltekst','$djnavn','$site','$fk_id','$billedefilnavn')") or die (mysql_errno());

        if(!$insert) {
            echo "Fejlede at gemme i databasen!";
            echo "<a href='index.php'>forside</a>";
        }
        else {
           echo "<a href='index.php'>forside</a>";
        }

    ?>


<form action="opretbruger_info.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" onsubmit="return validatePasswords()">
            <div id="boxinfo">
                <!-- bruger infomation-->
                <p>Brugerinfomation</p>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email til Brugernavn">
                <br>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
                <input type="password" id="gentag" name="gentag" placeholder="Gentag password">
            </div>
            <div id="boxinfo2">
                <!-- Dj infomation-->
                    <p>Dj infomation</p>
                    <input type="text" name="site" placeholder="Website Navn" id="formboxprofil">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" id="formboxprofil">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="djnavn" placeholder="Dj Navn" id="formboxprofil">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="land" placeholder="Hvor kommer du fra" id="formboxprofil">
                    <br>
                            <?php
                                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM musik_info';
                                    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                                    $select = '<select name="kategori">';
                                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                                    $select .= '<option value="'.$row['musikid'].'">'.$row['navn_musik'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                    $select .= '</select>';
                                    print $select;
                            ?>
            </div>
         <!-- Profil Tekst-->
            <div id="boxinfo3">
                <p>Profil Tekst</p>
                <textarea name="profiltekst" id="profiltekst" style="width:410px; height:155px;"></textarea>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="uploadfile"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Godkendt & Opret Bruger" id="godkendt_bruger">
            </div>
     </form>
```

What is my problem so it does not bother to work? It does not come up with some error or the like but this here is how my database like this:

[image http://jesperbok.dk/skoleopgave/db.png](http://jesperbok.dk/skoleopgave/db.png)

Comment: Try `mysql_error()` instead of `_errno`, print out your query before sending it and add further print statements to debug the code flow.

Comment: add this code at top of your php part: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` . reload - get error - update this post and add the error message

Answer (score 2):

you are inserting 2 email values. mysql will only let you set one value for email

> $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO brugere
>   (**EMAIL**,password,facebook,land,profiltekst,**EMAIL**,site,fk_musik_info,profilbillede)
>   VALUES
>   ('$email','$password','$facebook','$land','$profiltekst','$djnavn','$site','$fk_id','$billedefilnavn')")